# Build a collection of all elements that are selected and not

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I would like to make a collection of all elements that are selected and not.

The dom element consists of several `multiple select`.
Each of them have the same users.
My goal is to create a collection of all users and for the user which are selected add an attribute with a specific value.

Here is my code js code (1) and here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/vxRtb/9/.

My code works, but I would like to dry the code because, maybe, lopping just on the first select to get all the user is not required.
Any hints how to dry the following js code?
Please read the comments on the js code for more info; thanks

P.S.:
1) I am using `jQuery` and `underscore`
2) From the server I get the html code, the same as in jsfiddle.net/vxRtb/9

---

```
$(function () {
    var $selectElements = $('form .controls select');
    var userCollection = []; 

    // Subroutine_1
    // TODO Subroutine_1 and Subroutine_2 seems too close; any idea how to dry this code?
    $.each($($selectElements[0]), function (i, teamElement) {
        var $users = $(teamElement).find('option')

        $.each($users, function (i, user) {
            userCollection.push({
                id: $(user).val(),
                name: $(user).text(),
            });            
        });
    });

    // Subroutine_2
    $.each($selectElements, function (i, teamElement) {
        var $teamElement = $(teamElement);
        //var teamId = $teamElement.attr('id');
        var teamName = $teamElement
            .parent().parent().closest('.controls')
            .find('input').val();
        var $users = $teamElement.find('option:selected');

        $.each($users, function (i, user) {
            _.where(userCollection, {id: $(user).val()})[0].team = teamName;           
        });
    });

    console.log(userCollection);
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old question and you've probably moved on from it, however, I took a try at this and here's what I came up with.

### Analysis

The loops are very similar with the key difference of one loop builds up the team members and the other loop figures out their team. I think the DRY option is to only use one loop and test if a member has a team or not. There will be repetition as the user id's are non-unique, so some logic needs to be applied.

### Pseudo Code

1. Create User Object Collection based off of the `<option>` tag.

   1. Use getMyTeam to generate the team name
2. Group the User Objects by ID.
3. Filter User Objects taking only those with a team names
4. Filter User Objects without team names to show only uniq records

### Code

I'm not sure if this is any better. Performance-wise, this should be fairly poor due to all the nesting. However, I guess the advantage is that the code becomes much more modular and you can easily change the rules if needed. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxRtb/13/)

```
$(function () {

    // Helper to find a team based on an options element
    function getMyTeam() {
        if (this.is(':selected')) {
            var select = this.parent();
            var teamId = select.attr('id').replace(/_participations$/, '_name');
            return $('#' + teamId).val();
        }
        return undefined;
    };

    // Helper to return an object's id
    function getId(obj) {
        return obj.id;
    };

    // Helper to filter the team members by team name.
    function filterMembersByTeam(members) {
        var result = _.filter(members, function(record) {
            return !_.isUndefined(record['team']);
        });
        if (result.length === 0) { 
            result = _.uniq(members, true, function(member) {
                return JSON.stringify(member);
            })
        };
        return result;
    };

    // 1. Select the users
    var options = $('form .controls select option');

    // 2. Build up the user data
    var userCollection = _.map(options, 
                          function(option) {
                            return { 
                                    id: $(option).val(),
                                    name: $(option).text(),
                                    team: getMyTeam.apply($(option)) 
                                };
                          }); 

    // 3. Clean & filter the user data
    userCollection = 
        _.flatten( 
            _.map( _.groupBy(userCollection, getId), filterMembersByTeam) 
        );

    console.log(userCollection);
});
```